# How to get distinct prices by product with single row per product

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, aggregate-functions, string-aggregation

Order contains same product with different prices.

How to get list of distinct prices per product in order, with one row per product?

I tried

```
SELECT product, string_AGG(DISTINCT price::text, ',' ORDER BY price)
 FROM (VALUES ('A', 100), ('A', 200) , ('B', 200))
orderdetail (product, price)
GROUP BY product
```

but got error

```
ERROR:  in an aggregate with DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in argument list
LINE 1: ...ct, string_AGG(DISTINCT price::text, ',' ORDER BY price DESC...
```

How to fix this ?

Postgres 9.4 is used.

This is probably required to create answer for
[How to find changed prices in last two purchase invoices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838695/how-to-find-changed-prices-in-last-two-purchase-invoices)

Comment: price is second column in orderdetail table ::text is postgres cast which changes its type to text to get string price list. It can probably written as `cast(price as text)` in standard sql

Comment: When you say 'How to get list of distinct prices per product in order?', do you mean with a single row per product?

Comment: Yes, single row per product containing list of different prices in ascending order. Second column can probably be also array instead of string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your error message, and from [what I read here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180418/ordering-distinct-column-values-by-first-value-of-other-column-in-aggregate-fu) from gurus like @GordonLinoff, you can't use `DISTINCT` inside `STRING_AGG`.  A quick workaround would be to just subquery your table first and use `DISTINCT` there to remove duplicates.

```
SELECT t.product, STRING_AGG(t.price::text, ',' ORDER BY price)
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT product, price
    FROM (VALUES ('A', 100), ('A', 100), ('A', 200), ('B', 200), ('B', 200))
    orderdetail (product, price)
) t
GROUP BY t.product
```

I tested this query on Postgres, and it returns this:

```
product | string_agg
text    | text
A       | 100,200
B       | 200
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I expected that there is some native syntax for this.